# Email workflow 2010

Tags: workflow, email, send-to-destination

I created a `list` (birthday's this month). In this `list` there are three columns (photo, employee and date birthday). I added new item in this `list`: upload a photo, choose employee from AD and choose date of employee birthday. I want to create a `workflow` in SharePoint Designer 2010. How to send an email to chosen employee on the date of his birthday?